# asp.net core 2.0 send model object from View to Controller Action

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have this Invitation View:

```
@model Invitation
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Invite" method="post">
    Email: <input asp-for="InvitedUserEmailAddress" /> <br />
    Display Name: <input asp-for="InvitedUserDisplayName" /> <br />
    Redirect URL: <input asp-for="InviteRedirectUrl" /> <br />
    Include Message: <input asp-for="SendInvitationMessage" /> <br />
    <button type="submit">Invite</button>
</form>
```

How do I send the filled out Invitation model to my controller action specified in the form, so that I can use it to send an invitation.

The controller action looks something like this:

```
    public async void Invite()
    {
        PostGraphAsync(invitation); //want invitation object from view
    }
```

Comment: Don't return `void` in an action method...

Comment: @DavidG Okay, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did almost everything right.

Just receive the model in the Action argument.

```
public async void Invite(Invitation invitation)
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Do you know how I can stop it from redirecting to Home/Invite after pressing the button? I don't want a redirect, want it to just stay on the same view

Comment: Without refreshing(Ajax) ? or with refresh, but to reload the same view ?

Comment: I dont need a refresh :)

Comment: Then you will need some kind of ajax call in order to execute an http request to the server. Example: https://liftcodeplay.com/2017/02/14/using-asp-net-core-and-jquery-to-call-methods-via-ajax/